# AWS - NAT Gateway causing slow outgoing requests

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have EC2 instances across two availability zones, that are behind an ELB.  The EC2 instances are in a private subnet and have route table rules setup to use a NAT Gateway.

These instances make a lot of requests to SQS, and every so often, one of those requests takes a very long time.  I'm wondering if my NAT Gateway is a bit of a bottleneck in this situation?  Is the NAT gateway meant to be used for frequent, time-sensitive, outgoing requests, or is it meant more for things like Software Updates which don't necessarily need to be done in a timely manner?

Also, my application has very little traffic (< 100 rpm) so I don't believe it's related to that.  Moreover, each availability zone has it's own NAT Gateway.

Comment: Can you add some metrics from SQS? Messages IN, Messages OUT? Also when you say one of the request's take long time, how much? Is it timing out?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni its not timing out, but for example, if I setup a health check from the ELB (every 15 seconds lets say), and I have my application send a basic RequestLogging message to SQS on each, they generally take about 50ms.  However, a handful every hour take about 1000ms.  And according to NewRelic, the time is taken trying to connect to SQS

Comment: NAT Gateways are highly efficient and should not cause any bottle necks. I believe this has something to do with the messages itself that you post to SQS. What is the size of the messages, the ones that take about 1000ms?

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, are you using SQS to log your messages some place?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni The messages are very small.  Generally about 1KB.   We're using SQS for various things -- one of which is some basic request logging.  The example with the health check was more to just setup a basic test where the health check was the only thing happening in the app.

Comment: Could it be with the connection pool? What is the max pool size?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni how do I view that on an ubuntu box?

Comment: I meant the SQS client connection pool for which ever language's AWS SDK you are using. It should be in your code where you configure the SQS client and connect to SQS.

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni I'll have to take a look.  It's a PHP app (actually, Laravel) and the SQS connection is part of the Laravel framework.

Comment: Were you able to figure out?

Comment: It seems to be unrelated to the NAT Gateway.  I sent some SQSrequest IDs to AWS support so we'll see what they say

Comment: Great. Would love to hear what they say.